# The method getIntent() is undefined for the type GetLRL

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to pass data from `createCheckboxList` method to the getLRL class but when I try to call getIntent in the `post_selected` GetLRL class I am getting this error `The method getIntent() is undefined for the type GetLRL`

How can I fix it?

createCheckboxList in the MainActivity:

```
private void createCheckboxList(final ArrayList<Integer> items) {
        this.items = items;
        final ArrayList<Integer> selected = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ...

            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {       
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GetLRL.class);
                    intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra("selected_route", selected);
                    startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

post_selected method in the GetLRL:

```
public void post_selected() {
//  here is the error
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null && extras.containsKey("selected_route")) {

        ArrayList<Integer> routeList = extras
                .getIntegerArrayList("selected_route");

    }

    //new MyAsyncTask(context).execute(jSONString);
}
```

Comment: `GetLRL` is not an `Activity`; otherwise, `getIntent()` would be available. You are trying to start `GetLRL` as an activity, but it is not inheriting from `Activity`, so this will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetLRL class must be an Activity (`extends Activity`), if it is not, then the undefined method exception will be thrown